# Powershell code (Get-Date).AddDays(-maxvalue)?

Tags: powershell

try running this code:

```
(Get-date).AddDays(-735983)
```

with values bigger than what I've put (as of 21.01.2016).
Question is strictly theoretical.
Why I can't go past 1st of January 0001 A.D.? Or maybe, how can I go past that day with this simple cmdlet?

And also:

Why max value in this expression is:

```
(Get-date).AddDays(2916075)
```

How possibly am I able to go past the date 31st of December 9999 A.D.?

Comment: `[DateTime]::MinValue;[DateTime]::MaxValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dates are the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` of the `DateTime` class, so it's by design.

Example (in Norwegian):

```
PS > [DateTime]::MinValue
mandag 1. januar 0001 00.00.00

PS > [DateTime]::MaxValue
fredag 31. desember 9999 23.59.59
```